# numbers.sequence in thymeleaf with thymeleaf variable

Tags: thymeleaf

This works :

```
<tr>
   <td th:text="${Blade__${iBladeIndex}__CutterMultiImagesCount}"></td>
</tr>
```

Returns the correct number in `<td>`

But this :

```
<tr th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, ${Blade__${iBladeIndex}__CutterMultiImagesCount} - 1)}">
    <td th:text="${i}"></td>
</tr>
```

returns an error :

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression
> [#numbers.sequence(0, ${Blade0CutterMultiImagesCount} - 1)] @22:
> EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'

It's wrapped around `<th:block th:with="iBladeIndex=|${iterstat.index}|">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be:

```
<tr th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, Blade__${iBladeIndex}__CutterMultiImagesCount - 1)}">
```

(I would recommend not using preprocessing in most cases though.)

Comment: Thanks - this worked - but can you tell me why not to use preprocessing ?